# non metrizability of pointwise convergence

Tags: real-analysis

I have some question concerning the topology of pointwise convergence, when I was trying to understand the following paper titled:  A NOTE ON POINTWISE CONVERGENCE by Marion K Fort, Jr:

http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1951-002-01/S0002-9939-1951-0040647-7/S0002-9939-1951-0040647-7.pdf

The paper tries to show that there does not exists a metric $d$ for $C$ with the property that $lim_{m,n \rightarrow \infty} d(f_{n},f_{0}) = 0$ if and only if the sequence $f_{n}$ converges pointwise to $f_{0}$.

I understand this question has been asked before as well as this paper has been referred to in the answers on this forum.  I came across this question a long time ago in an homework assignment and later i tried to read and understand the paper on and off but have not succeed due to the way the paper was written.
I was wondering if I can get some help with demystifying some of my confusion.

For each point I need help with, i have referenced the paper with paragraph number.

On paragraph 6, it states:  "We now let $T$ be the collection of all intervals $J$ such that for some $n$, $J$ is an interval of the subdivision $S_{n}$."  Here if I have a set $T$, do I pick one interval $J$ for every number $n$, also how is the interval $J$ chosen?

On paragraph 7, "Let $n$ and $m$ be positive integers.  We define the function $f_{{n},{m}}$.  If $J$ is an interval of the subdivision $S_{n}$, we define $\epsilon_{J} = 1$ if $k(J) \leq m$ and $\epsilon_{J} = 1/k(J) > m$.  Let $f_{{n},{m}}$ be the function on $[0,1]$ which is of type ($m$, $\epsilon_{J}$) on each interval $J$ of $S_{n}$.  The graph of $f_{{n},{m}}$ has a hump on each interval of $S_{n}$.  It is easily seen that $f_{{n},{m}}$ is continuous, however, since if $\delta > 0$ then the graph of $f_{{n},{m}}$ can contain at most a finite number of humps of height greater than $\delta$.

My question are as follows, from this point on in the paper, are $m$, and $n$ fixed positive integers?
The way the function $f_{{n},{m}}$ is defined, is there suppose to some kind of analytic expression for it, because I am seeing a function $k:T \rightarrow N$ where $k(J)=n$, and also the function $\epsilon_{J}$.  I am guessing $f_{{n},{m}}$ is defined as $f_{{n},{m}}(\epsilon_{J})$ which I am not sure if it is correct.  Also, how is the function being type ($m$, $\epsilon_{J}$) related to how $f$ is defined earlier being of type ($n$, $\epsilon$).

For paragraph 8, I am not sure how the author conclude that $f_{{n},{m}} = 0$ for all but at most three values of $m$.

for paragraph 9, I don't understand how the value for $N_{n}$ is determined.

Thank you in advance for any help you can give me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The paper is written in the terse style preferred by journals and professional mathematicians (and to be honest, I quite like it as well even though it requires that the reader keeps stopping and checking that they've really understood what was just said).  It gets easier to read with practice, and asking questions about the material in here is expected: don't get disheartened.

Answering the questions as you've indexed them:

- paragraph 6: this is actually a statement about the structure of $T$, not the numbers $n$.  The elements of $T$ are intervals, referred to generally as $J$, and if you pick any such $J$ then it must belong to an $S_n$ for some $n$, no matter what that $n$ is.  What matters here is that all the elements of $T$ are like this: you're not choosing $T$, it's being defined for you.  If you wanted to choose a specific one (perhaps to work an example through) then you would pick a value for $n$ and then look at $S_n$ and then choose endpoints for $J$ such that $J \subseteq S_n$.  This is then an element of $T$ by construction.
- paragraph 7: $n$ and $m$ are positive integers, yes.  They are fixed in the sense that whenever $f_{n,m}$ is referred to you could replace them with fixed positive integers, but the exact choice may vary from one usage of $f_{n,m}$ to the next (e.g. one example might work easily with $f_{1,3}$ but the next might work better with $f_{100,300}$, especially since we're thinking about convergence).
- para7 cont'd: $f$ is analytic but it would be hard to write down an explicit expression for it, which is why it's being defined in this way.  In analysis we often find pathological functions (those that behave badly enough to act as counter-examples ;-) ) that oscillate wildly or jump erratically and it's easier to describe them than to write them out in symbols.
- para7 cont'd: $f_{n,m}$ is not $f_{n,m}(e_J)$; rather $f_{n,m}$ is given by the original function $f$ applied to values $m$ and $e_J$.  That's what's meant by saying that $f_{n,m}$ is of type $(m,e_J)$.  By the definition of a function of type $(n,\epsilon)$ we therefore have that:

  - the domain of $f_{n,m}$ contains $[a,b]$
  - the graph of $f_{n,m}$ restricted to $[a,b]$ consists of the piecewise continuous line joining $(a,0)$, $(x_m, 0)$, $(x_{m+1},e_J)$, $(x_{m+2},e_J)$, $(x_{m+3},0)$ and $(b,0)$ where $e_J = 1$ if $k(J) \leq m$ and $e_J = 1/k(J)$ if $k(J) > m$.  Thus each $f_{n,m}$ is a hump function whose exact shape depends on the injective function $k:T\rightarrow {\mathbb Z}^+$
- paragraph 8: we fix $n$ first, so we have restricted ourselves to those $J$ that live in $S_n$ for this fixed $n$.  That determines the values that $m$ can take (because $S_n$ is a normal subdivision that defines exactly what values $m$ can take on), and so this restricts $f(t)$ for $0\leq t\leq 1$ to just three non-zero values.  For any fixed $n$ then, $f_{n,m}=0$ for all but at most three values of $m$.
- paragraph 9: $f_0$ is defined to be identically zero so that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} d(f_{n,m},f_0) = 0$ for each positive integer $n$.  This means that the $f_{n,m}$ are converging to $f_0$ so when $m$ is large enough we know that $f_{n,m}$ and $f_0$ are as close together as we like. Since $n$ is fixed we can do this for each value of $n$.  So, pick $N_n$ so that $d(f_{n,m},f_0) < 1/n$ (for each $n$) (for any given example function $f_{n,m}$ you write down you can find the right value of $N_n$).

You're still going to need to think about all of this before it really makes sense, I suspect.  Try picking a value $n$ (say $n=4$) and an interval $J$ in $S_n$ and a function $k$ and draw out the graph of $f_{n,m}$ -- that picture should help put all these words into context.

EDIT: your comment says you're still confused a little, so:
\begin{eqnarray}
S_1 & = & \{0,1\}\quad \mbox{by hypothesis,} \\
S_2 & = & \left\{0,\frac{1}{2}, \frac{3}{4}, \frac{7}{8}, \ldots, 1\right\} \\
S_3 & = & \left\{0, \frac{1}{4}, \frac{3}{8}, \ldots, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{5}{8}, \frac{11}{16}, \ldots, \frac{3}{4}, \ldots, 1 \right\} \\
S_4 & = & \left\{0, \frac{1}{8}, \frac{3}{16}, \ldots, \frac{1}{4}, \frac{5}{16}, \frac{11}{32}, \ldots, \frac{3}{8}, \ldots, 1\right\}
\end{eqnarray}
Note that each $S_n$ refines the previous $S_n$ by iterating the subdivision procedure over each new interval formed.
The $f_{n,m}$ are then defined on the $S_n$, and here is a picture of $f_{3,1}, f_{3,2}$ and $f_{3,3}$ where I assume that $k(J) = 2$ for convenience:
[image: The first three functions for $S_3$]
It should now be clear (look at the graph between about $0.23$ and $0.25$) that the functions overlap at most three-at-a-time, which is why $f_{n,m}$ is non-zero for at most three values of $m$.  You might want to add in $f_{3,4}$ and $f_{3,5}$ yourself to convince yourself of that.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on paragraph 8.  I am still confused here.  If we have let n=1, there are five points 0, $x_{1}=1/2$, $x_{2}=2/3$, $x_{3}=3/4$, $x_{4}=4/5$, 1 with coordinates (0,0), (1/2, $0$), (2/3, $0$), (3/4, $\epsilon_{J}$), (4/5, $\epsilon_{J}$), (1,0), so if say we pick a m say m=5, do I do a normal subdivision on each of the four sub-intervals, being {(0,0), (1/2, $0$)}, {(1/2, $0$), (2/3, $0$)}, {(2/3, $\epsilon_{J}$), (4/8, $\epsilon_{J}$)}, {(4/8, $0$), (1, 0)}.   $\epsilon_{J} = 1 or 1/k(J)$ depending on whether k(J) is $\leq$ m or $>$ m.

Comment: I've added more detail to the answer: I've got no idea where you got your five points from so I've also shown how the subdivisions work.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  I think what i am confused about when i try what you suggested from your response are the way the functions k(J), $\epsilon_{J}$ are defined in relation to the output value of $f_{{m}, {n}}$.  Fort just stated that k is a mapping from T to the positive integers.  Also, the way $\epsilon_{J}$ was defined, how is that related to the output value $f_{{m}, {n}}$.  Do I determine whether the value of  $f_{{m}, {n}}$ greater than or equal to zero solely by $\epsilon_{J}$.

Comment: If so, i am confused about what it means to concretely decide which interval J to pick for each $S_n$ and then map it to the set of positive integers   For each $S_n$, it is stated a function is of type (n, $\epsilon_{J}$) with lines joining a five different coordinate points.  $a, x_{n}, x_{n+1}, x_{n+2}, x_{n+3}, b$, make up the J intervals.

Comment: Finally, the way Fort defined for m, and n, would there be limitation as to whether m or n can or can not be greater than each other once the value of n is fixed.  

One final thing, this question in particular, does not use any tools of point set topology, would this question be easier to solve if employing the help of separation axioms.  Thanks

Comment: You might be better off making some of these new questions on the site. However: $f_{n,m}$ is given as a graph, not as an analytic formula.  You can work out an analytic formula for some $n$ and $m$ if you want; you will need to choose a suitable $k(J)$ first though.  $f_{n,m}$ is *always* greater than or equal to zero (did you look at the image?).
Your second new comment needs to be a new question, I can't answer that in a comment.
Finally, $n$ can be greater than $m$ or less than $m$, it doesn't matter for the proof.  They're just indices to show how the convergence proceeds.

Comment: can you  explain how you concretely picked J for the function K(J), and why you decide to map it to 2.  Alsohen you pick m, does it has any relations to the function K(J)?  Thanks.

Comment: I didn't pick $J$ for $k(J)$.  In fact, I haven't picked any $J$ at all, I just set $k(J)$ to be $2$ for the purpose of the example.  You need to choose your function $k:T\rightarrow \mathbb N$, and then $k(J)$ will be defined whenever you need it.
The value of $e_J$ is determined by the relative values of $k(J)$ and $m$, as the paper shows you on the first page.

Comment: sorry, i am still  not clear by what you mean by I have to choose a function for $k:T \rightarrow N$.  Do you mean i have write out what the expression for the function $k(J)$ is:  like $k(J)=n$ where n belongs to $N^{+}$, and n is decide by fixing it to be some values along with m.

Comment: after looking more at it for a couple days, I think I have figured out what what you are trying to explained.  Thank you again for all your responses.